# How can tungsten be a conductor and also have high resistance?

Tags: resistance

Why is rubber or plastic not used as a filament in an incandescent bulb? Since rubber and plastic have high resistivity which is much higher than tungsten. If tungsten has high resistance even though it is a metal then how is this so? Metals should have lesser resistivity. Am I right?

---

Also worth noting is the fact that the filament has a positive temp. coefficient. This means its resistance rises with temperature.

Comment: In order to heat up a filament, you need power (Watts). Power is the product of current and voltage. 1) Given a constant voltage, how does current relate to resistivity? 2) Given a constant current, how does voltage relate to resistivity?

Comment: A filament needs to be the appropriate resistance to deliver the required power. Following your logic, the best resistance would be an open circuit.

Comment: That's two very broad questions along the same lines in two days. Both asking why a bulb has a high resistance despite the answers to the previous question saying that it doesn't. If you have trouble understanding the answers you've had please ask for clarification rather than asking a similar question again.

Comment: The original Swan light bulbs used carbonised paper, which is somewhat conductive. Rubber and plastic are normally considered *insulators*! So they're not used because they wouldn't work!

Answer (score 9):

Tungsten is a good conductor. Resistivity of tungsten is only about twice that of aluminum, and tungsten has lower resistance than iron, steel, platinum, lead.   Note that the filament lead-in wires are typically iron, which has nearly twice the resistivity of tungsten.  Why doesn't the iron light up, and the tungsten remain dark?

Light bulb filaments aren't resistive because of the tungsten.  They're resistive because of their very long length, and very thin wire.   The filament in a clear bulb appears spiralled, right?   It's clearly much longer than it looks, and much thinner.   But in many bulbs, the spiral itself is composed of even smaller spirals.  (Some large high-wattage bulbs even have yet a third level of smaller spirals.)  A 2cm filament may actually be many tens of cm of extremely thin wire, as below:

[image]
[image: Coiled Coil Tungsten fliament]

We use tungsten not because it's especially resistive, but because it's "refractory," and most other inexpensive metals would melt long before they heat up to "white" temperatures above 2500Kdeg.  Early lightbulbs used filaments of platinum, iridium, rhodium, etc., but Edison's bamboo-carbon filaments made bulbs affordable.

Answer (score 5):

*Why is rubber or plastic not used as a filament in an incandescent bulb?*

**Think for a minute**

Why does an incandescent produce light ? Because the (tungsten) filament inside it is heated to around 2800 K (Kelvin) by the electrical power. At 2800 K it glows brightly.

Now what happens to rubber or plastic when heated to 2800 K ?

These materials will disintegrate and probably evaporate. Ergo: completely useless as an incandescent lamp filament.

*Metals should have lesser resistivity*

You mean, metals should be better **conductors**.

**Why** do you think that is so ? **Why** do you think **all metals** are good conductors ? Silicon is a metal yet when it is very pure it does not conduct electricity very well.

How well a material conducts electricity depends on its atomic structure, how easy it is for an electron to move around. This is not the same for all metals.

Here is an [Article](https://www.thebalance.com/electrical-conductivity-in-metals-2340117) about Electrical conductivity.

Comment: 5000K? I think you mean 3000K (or 5000F). Tungsten melts at 3695K.

Comment: OK, I used a number which I remembered seeing somewhere, according to Wikipedia the typical temperature is about 2800 K so I'll change it to that.

Comment: Silicon is not generally considered a metal.