# Is tungsten a good conductor of electricity?

Tags: temperature, resistivity

If yes, why does it give off light and heat in a filament? If no, why? Tungsten is a metal, isn't it?

My proposition is that it is a moderate conductor, and it happens to be ideal for usage as a filament.

I need some clarification..

Comment: Tungsten is used in lightbulb filaments because it has a very high melting point. Since you push the filament temperature very high to shift the spectrum towards visible light, you need some material that does not turn into a puddle. (edit puddle, not poodle).

Comment: I think all your questions could be answered by a simple google search and read through https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tungsten

Comment: It's actually *too good* until it heats up

Comment: @SredniVashtar: I think there would be a market for a metal that could turn into a Poodle when heated.

Comment: @ocrdu it is edited.. puddle. Btw, do all metals glow at some point or is it a property only of tungsten?

Comment: As far as I know all metals glow when heated, but I suppose some will burn or melt before they glow in visible light.

Comment: Not just metals. All _substances_ will glow when heated to those temperatures. The "glow" is called [_black body radiation_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black-body_radiation).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can tungsten be a conductor and also have high resistance?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/286852/how-can-tungsten-be-a-conductor-and-also-have-high-resistance)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tungsten is used as the filament in incandescent light bulbs because it has the highest melting point of any metal.

The filament is heated to 3000 °C (the higher the temperature, the greater the efficiency and whiter the light).

Here's a comparison of the properties of Silver and Tungsten that may clarify your doubts.

[image]

The heat generated by the filament would be I²R watts, where 'I' would be the current in amperes and 'R' the resistance in ohms.

A 120V 60W incandescent light bulb filament would have a cold resistance of 30 Ω and a working resistance of 240 Ω. It would draw 0.5 A and dissipate 60 W.

Incandescent lamp filaments are protected from damage, due to oxidation, by their vacuum or inert gas working environment.